# pyserialでreadしたデータの文字比較

Tags: python

Pyserialを使って受信データに応じて処理を変えようとして以下を書きました。
print文の結果は"TEST"が表示されるのですが、その際に"OK"まで行きません。
対策を教えてください。(Python 2.7.3)

```
import serial
port = "/dev/rfcomm0"
baudrate = 115200
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)

while 1:
   if ser.inWaiting > 0
      print ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
      if ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) == "TEST"
　　　   print ("OK")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printするためにser.read()を読み込んでしまっています。if文でser.read()するときにはその続きを読み込もうとするはずです。以下のように修正すれば良いかと思います。

```
while 1:
   if ser.inWaiting() > 0
      data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
      print data
      if data == "TEST"
　　　   print ("OK")
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 回答を "採用" してもらえると嬉しいです :)

Comment: ご連絡が遅れてすいません。採用しました。

Comment: うーん、採用になってなさそう..

Comment: すいません。採用の仕方を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png この画像にあるようなチェックがありませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。今度こそ採用しました。

Comment: ありがとう！採用いただきました！